# font size in chart.correlation (performanceAnalytics)

Tags: fonts, size, correlation, performanceanalytics

I use and like the function `chart.correlation` (package: PerformanceAnalytics), however the entanglement of the coefficient's font size with the correlation extent is unpleasant, leading to unreadable numbers.

Can anyone tell me whether it's possible to change/fix the font size of the coefficients in the graph? I'd like them all to have the same size.
Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
trace("chart.Correlation", edit=T) #to edit function
```

then in line 17, change the cex value for what you want, i changed it for 3

```
 cex <- 3
```

then run the function

```
chart.Correlation(df_corr, histogram = F, method = c("pearson"))
```

#the end